# Can't install command line tools on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, command-line, big-sur

After updating my OS to Big Sur, I tried cloning a repo.  In order to do so, I apparently need to install command-line tools.  However, on Big Sur, whenever I try to download command-line tools, I get this warning and no installation.

[image]

Comment: @anki `Scotts-iMac:Desktop scottlydon$ git init
sh: line 1:  4306 Bus error: 10           /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find git 2> /dev/null
git: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /.../SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find git 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 35328: (null) (errno=Invalid argument)
xcode-select: Failed to locate 'git', requesting installation of command line developer tools.`

Comment: Check if you can use brew for the time being. Not a lot can be done for beta. How did you attempt to install the CLT ? Can you try downloading it from the website ?

Comment: I tried to install CLT from the popup that appeared when attempting `git clone` and then attempting to install it from the website. Brew worked just fine.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the same issue for me by downloading and installing the latest CLT package from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: For some reason that didn't work for me. Only Home brew.

Comment: This worked great. With the macOS beta I wasn't able to get right version of command-line tools using the standard approaches. Big Sur beta has been a big pain.